# aggird export to excel is modifying data of numbers with more than 15 digits

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, export-to-excel, ag-grid-react

we are loading an aggrid on ui and when user right clicks on it and downloads an excel, a column which has more than 15 digits is loosing the last four digits and replaced with zeros.(It is shown as scientific format in excel and when we check the value on the cell it is different from what is shown on the grid)
Please advice

Comment: Can you convert it to string? Javascript cannot store number that large

Comment: I did, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this [Big Number](https://github.com/alexbardas/bignumber.js#readme) package which allows you to store and modify numbers larger than [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

Answer (score 0):

A number that contains more than 15 digits in Excel, it changes any digits past the fifteenth place to zeros. You can cast the column values to string on export.

```
//Use customizeData

    exportOptions: {
                       //--
                   },
    customizeData: function (data) {
                  var ind = data.header.indexOf("ColumnName"); // This code is to find the column name's index which you want to cast.
                  for (var i = 0; i < data.body.length; i++) {
                      data.body[i][ind] = '\u200C' + data.body[i][ind]; //will cast the number to string.
                    }
                 }
```

Error_Image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A39hf.png